# MSIX: Set Installation Path

Tags: msix

How to change the MSIX installation path??

```
    Referred this url - "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-behind-the-scenes"

    Always installer package is created in default location "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps"

    Need to set the installer location to different location.
```

Answer (score 0):

**The installation path of an MSIX package cannot be changed.** All the files you have included in your package are installed inside an app-specific folder under **"C:\Program Files\WindowsApps<your app>\"**.

This is a design decision from Microsoft. Only for MSI/EXE installers you can change the install path.

If you want to add files in other folders too, you need to copy them the first time your application is launched. For that, you have multiple options. You can write your own code inside your application to copy the files in other folders or you can use tools like Advanced Installer to do it for you.

To understand more about [MSIX and how files outside of the installation path can be managed I recommend this article/presentation](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/vfs-files-management.html) I wrote last month.

Comment: One note to add here, you can change the installation directory for ALL Msix packages by using the  Add-AppxVolume